# Updated Component fields are not getting changed on UI

Tags: angular

I am trying to update a variable in the component which is being displayed on UI. After changing the variable contents the UI has not updated with the changed value. But in logs, I am getting the right content. How to resolve this and why this is happening?

Both the components are a child to a third component. (Basically child-child communication)

First component(OrderListComponent):

```
export class OrderListComponent {
page = 1;
Orderlist: SingleOrder[];
ngOnInit() {}
populateOrderList(){
    this.service.refreshList()
    .subscribe(
    data => {
       this.Orderlist = data;
       this.page=2;
       console.log(this.page);// printing as 2 in logs
    })}
```

First component HTML looks like this:

```
<label>{{page}}</label> // printing 1 as it is set by default in code
```

Second Component(the calling one):

```
 // Second component (Single-Order)
 @Component({
  providers: [OrderListComponent]
 })
 export class SingleOrderComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private orderlist:OrderListComponent ) {}
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
   this.orderlist.populateOrderList();
}}
```

I tried changing the first component code as below by using the change detector

First component(OrderListComponent):

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush//tried default strategy also but no change
})
export class OrderListComponent {
page = 1;
Orderlist: SingleOrder[];
ngOnInit() {}
populateOrderList(){
    this.service.refreshList()
    .subscribe(
    data => {
       this.Orderlist = data;
       this.page=2;
       this.cd.detectChanges(); // used this but no change
       // tried this.cd.markForCheck() , even no change
       console.log(this.page);// printing as 2 in logs
    })}
```

Wanted to see value 2 on UI but receiving 1 only. As I am new to angular 7 couldn't find quickly. Pls, help me out in this...

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not inject other components to communicate with them, instead you should use a service to do this job.

In your service have an `@Output` property which will be an `EventEmitter`:

```
@Output() triggerChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Inject this service in the `SingleOrderComponent` and call the `emit` of the `EventEmitter` method like so:

```
constructor(private service: CommunicationService) { }
 onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.triggerChange.emit();
 }
```

And in the other component, inject the same service and just subscribe to this event:

```
this.service.triggerChange.subscribe(()=>{
  this.service.refreshList()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.page=2;
       console.log(this.page);// printing as 2 in logs
    });
  });
```

And when the event is emitted you can call the `refreshList()` to update your component.

This is an working example in Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cancvb

Also you are injecting a new component instance every time as you did :

```
providers: [OrderListComponent]
```

So the changes you did are not reflecting in the component in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation and it worked for me.